# PDFTK Location (500 Internal Error)

Tags: php, pdf, command-line, pdftk

So I have PDFTK installed, and seems to work when inside the root directory. (IE: /public_html/)  But as soon as I move my script into a 'folder' (IE: /public_html/test/) it forms a 500 Internal Server Error.

This is the code I have, and have tested.

```
// Option 1
$command = 'pdftk test/FormTest.pdf fill_form test/FormTestData.fdf output output.pdf flatten';

// Option 2
$command = '/usr/bin/pdftk test/FormTest.pdf fill_form test/FormTestData.fdf output output.pdf flatten';

// Option 3
$command = '/usr/local/bin/pdftk test/FormTest.pdf fill_form test/FormTestData.fdf output output.pdf flatten';

$response = passthru($command);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

These options all seem to return the same ERROR (500).
The weird part is when I run it within the root of the site, it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems as though my 'folder' permissions were having issues, 777 causes the error, 755 seems to be better... but still not able to get the OUTPUTTED FILE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue where I had installed PDFTK. All is working now.